# ImportError: No module named _smbus_cffi

Tags: python, linux, debian

Okay, I'am programming a robot with pi2go.py imported to my program. I'am running Linux debian on Raspberry pi (Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19-v7+). Pi2go imports pca9685.py that imports smbus. First of all, the smbus was not installed on my system so I got a smbus-cffi package for python. Ok, now I copied the smbus directory to the same directory as my files are, then after that I installed it python said that I'am trying to get a relative package something like that I don't remember the error exactly but something on this way, Ok, I added from smbus to the import statement that imports smbus:

Here is the pca9685.py: (I only changed the import statement So this is just a part of it):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# PCA9685 Library
# Purely used for Pi2Go, so not as flexible as other libraries
#
# Created by Gareth Davies, Feb 2016
# Copyright 4tronix
#
# This code is in the public domain and may be freely copied and used
# No warranty is provided or implied
#
#======================================================================
from smbus import smbus, time
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

PCA = 0x40    # Fixed I2C Address of PC9685
SERVOS = 6+48
RED = 14
GREEN = 10
and program continues...
```

Then, I try to run my program again, and there is a error that says:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linetest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pi2go
  File "/home/pi/pi2go/pi2go.py", line 121, in <module>
    import pca9685
  File "/home/pi/pi2go/pca9685.py", line 14, in <module>
    from smbus import smbus, time
  File "/home/pi/pi2go/smbus/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .smbus import ffi
  File "/home/pi/pi2go/smbus/smbus.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ._smbus_cffi import ffi
ImportError: No module named _smbus_cffi
```

These is all the things in my folder:

```
__about__.py  lightTest.py  pca9685.pyc      smbus         switchTest.py
beebot1.py    linetest.py   pi2go.py         smbuscffi     testLEDs.py
beebot.py     lineTest.py   pi2go.pyc        smbus-cffi    util.py
__init__.py   liteTest.py   servod           smbus.py
IRTest.py     motorTest.py  servoTest.py     smbus.pyc
LEDTest.py    pca9685.py    sgh_PCF8591P.py  sonarTest.py
```

So, the question is, I'am I doing this completely wrong or where do I get the module __smbus_cffi? I have looked everywhere after this __smbus_cffi module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appeared that I was using a wrong package.
Here is what I did:

I followed the instructions on this site:

Here are these commands: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=99980

And then I just ran the code with python.

And that's all! I did not know what I needed so this became a major problem! But, very simple to fix.